# Adding existent files to Delphi Project and switch them between branches

Tags: delphi, branch, delphi-xe3

I have more than one branch of my source code (Dev - Tst - Main) for each Delphi project, but also, I have the same structure for the folder where I have my base files. The base files are units that I share in most of my projects.

The problem I´m facing, is that I need to change between branches of this folder, and its really tedious to change the path manually.

For example:

[image]

The folder Main contains all the units from my Main branch.

If I want switch to the Tst branch, I need to change the folder from Main to Tst.

For this, I have to remove ..\Main\ATestUnit.pas from my project and add ..\Tst\ATestUnit.pas.

The issue I´m facing is that I have lots of units in this folder, and some of them, have dependency between them. Adding these by hand, becomes a really tedious task.

I was thinking that there might be some other solution. Using some predefined configuration in the Delphi IDE where I can switch between directories easily.

Is there any way to do this? Like setting paths in the configuration of the program? The kind of configuration that we do in debug or release options.

Comment: Pretty hard to understand. Perhaps all you need is to use search directories. However, the basic organisation feels a bit dubious.

Comment: Perhaps if you add projects in the Project Group which point to the folders you want? For example, you can have ProjectMain, ProjectTest, ProjectDev?